# How to Remove this Ransome ware from my computer

Tags: database, encryption, virus, trojan

Today i opend my Computer and i saw that my all files are converted to KODC extension file .

i think it is a ransomware can any one help me how i do resolve this .

i have attached some screenshots for help .

Please help me guys!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trust me, you don't want to destroy your variable.

When you destroy a variable, you don't access it anymore.

Go ahead, try it, the code is

```
delete(myVar);
```

Instead, you should give it a new value, like so

```
myVar = null;
myVar = '';
setTimeout(() => myVar = ''); // triggers Angular change detection, can be useful for you
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. Why don't you simply call the destroy method on your table, and then create  it again the way you did it in your NgAfterViewInit method?

https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()

Comment: i did that but it was not working , by the way thanks i got the solution from my own thanks for the help